# Understanding the reason for email delay

Tags: email

We receive around 50+ emails from a bank that we work with. Sometimes, their emails are delayed by one day. We are trying to understand the issue and we are trying to fix it. We have put the domain to our whitelist. However, this has not resolved the issue. The header is below:

```
Return-Path: <hizmet@akbank.com>
Delivered-To: finans@kisan.com.tr
Received: from eu01.server.plus
                by eu01.server.plus with LMTP
                id +GgqGsZrO125hjMA7YZH9Q
                (envelope-from <hizmet@akbank.com>)
                for <finans@kisan.com.tr>; Fri, 26 Jul 2019 23:08:22 +0200
Return-path: <hizmet@akbank.com>
Envelope-to: finans@kisan.com.tr
Delivery-date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 23:08:22 +0200
Received: from mgtexc09.akbank.com ([217.169.192.78]:58257)
                by eu01.server.plus with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256)
                (Exim 4.92)
                (envelope-from <hizmet@akbank.com>)
                id 1hr7Ro-00Ejfk-A7
                for finans@kisan.com.tr; Fri, 26 Jul 2019 23:08:22 +0200
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    s=akbank; d=akbank.com;
    h=mime-version:from:to:date:subject:content-type:message-id;
    bh=SRGCYnnX9jEvWobQ/4qyFcljd9G9zWjrFHnuQhaxE5I=;
    b=j7FtRZkruwp8XQUgj+3C2+VvvSbDPORWakrAwdjhbrVtp7UPaw2QDTEWWTk+wT
      WFYfg8nWCoBkd629NdOVajluwZl0NfA81hXhysecR5/M8qhD95aB9DAV9TdGDK
      KwYyDMY7XHsJdGemO/LN3dN8+cDAM7KaZSkhVcYDFAOFkEg=
X-EMID: ELC-I-111-0-23615124-20190726175320-N
X-VirtualMta: urgent
X-ExpireDate: 2019/07/27
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: =?utf-8?Q?Akbank_=C5=9Eube_Bankac=C4=B1l=C4=B1=C4=9F=C4?=
=?utf-8?Q?=B1?= <hizmet@akbank.com>
To: <FINANS@KISAN.COM.TR>
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 17:53:20 +0300
Subject: Akbank E-Posta
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
                boundary="--boundary_13557_4d8914dd-fe01-4b7a-a7e6-972d03da3def"
Message-ID: <09a2d864143841a19be4a15d8f580efa@excmgts02.mgtsdmn.akb>
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-104.0
X-Spam-Score: -1039
X-Spam-Bar: ---------------------------------------------------
X-Ham-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "eu01.server.plus",

has NOT identified this incoming email as spam.  The original
message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
root\@localhost for details.

Content preview:  DeÃ°erli MÃ¼Ã¾terimiz, HesabÃ½nÃ½zÃ½n hareketlerini iÃ§eren
    ekstre bilgisi ekte yer almaktadÃ½r. Bilginize sunarÃ½z. 
 Content analysis details:   (-104.0 points, 7.0 required)
  pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-100 USER_IN_WHITELIST      From: address is in the user's white-list
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
  1.1 DATE_IN_PAST_06_12     Date: is 6 to 12 hours before Received: date
-2.0 RCVD_IN_RP_SAFE        RBL: Sender in ReturnPath Safe - Contact
                             safe-sa@returnpath.net
                             [Return Path SenderScore Safe List (formerly]
                     [Habeas Safelist) - <http://www.senderscorecertified.com>]
  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
  0.0 T_OBFU_PDF_ATTACH      BODY: PDF attachment with generic MIME type
  0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                             envelope-from domain
  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
                             valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                             author's domain
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
-3.0 RCVD_IN_RP_CERTIFIED   RBL: Sender in ReturnPath Certified -
                             Contact cert-sa@returnpath.net
                             [Return Path SenderScore Certified {formerly]
                       [Bonded Sender} - <http://www.senderscorecertified.com>]
-0.0 DKIMWL_WL_HIGH         DKIMwl.org - Whitelisted High sender
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-EsetId: 37303A299E82206F677464
```

Although this message appears to have been sent on Friday (July 26th), it was received by our Outlooks on Saturday (July 27th).

Comment: As we do not have access to the logs, I have emailed the third party company to provide me with explanation and logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your antispam server seem to have took around 4H/5H to analyse it and liberate the email, which is anormal.

Please validate your antispam server.

Per your log:

> Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 **17:53:20 +0300**

And the antispam server liberate it there;

> Delivery-date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 **23:08:22 +0200**

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "validate your antispam server"? We are using a third party VPS hosting with cpanel for our mail. Our cpanel is using SpamAssassin and we have added this domain to our white list for it to go through.

Comment: @SQLfreaq The email was handed to your mail server like, 5H after it was received. I'am not a cpanel expert at all, maybe just remove the spamassasin config to test it out then.

Comment: @SQLfreaq If you think it can be related to a cpanel config, then I would move the question there; https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, cpanel is offtopic there on ServerFault